# Using shared library within shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I want to use a shared library within a shared library but g++ is complaining...

That is how my test sample looks:

```
.                                                                                                                                      
├── extA                                                                                                                                
│   ├── a.cpp                                                                                                                           
│   ├── a.h                                                                                                                             
│   └── libA.so                                                                                                                         
├── extB                                                                                                                                
│   ├── b.cpp                                                                                                                           
│   ├── b.h                                                                                                                             
│   └── libB.so                                                                                                                         
└── main.cpp
```

a.h:

```
#pragma once

int f(void);
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

int f(void) {
        return 42;
}
```

b.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "a.h"

int g(void);
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"

int g(void) {
        return f();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "b.h"


int main(int, char **) {
        std::cout << g() << std::endl;

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I pretty sure that my way of compiling is wrong. That is what I do:

```
g++ -c -fpic a.cpp
g++ -shared -o libA.so a.o
```

to create libA.so,

```
g++ -c -fpic -I../extA b.cpp -L../extA -lA
g++ -shared -o libB.so b.o
```

to create libB.so (I think this way is incorrect) and finally:

```
g++ -IexB main.cpp -LextB -lB -o main
```

The last g++-call leads to the error msg:

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
extB/b.h:3:15: fatal error: a.h: No such file or directory
 #include "a.h"
               ^
compilation terminated.
```

Can someone tell me, what is the right way to compile/create libB.so?

Answer (score 1):

```
main.cpp:4:15: fatal error: b.h: No such file or directory
 #include "b.h"
               ^
```

The error is nothing to do with `libB.so` it means `main.cpp` cannot find `b.h`, which is a problem finding headers, nothing to do with the shared library file.

If `b.h` is not in the same directory as `main.cpp` then you need to tell the compiler how to find the header, e.g. by using `-IextB` when compiling `main.cpp`

The file `main.cpp` includes the header `b.h` and uses the function `g()` defined in `libB.so` so why are you compiling `main.cpp` telling it how to find `a.h` and linking to `libA.so`? It doesn't need that header or that library!

You probably just want to change `A` to `B` since that's what `main.cpp` actually depends on:

```
g++ -IextB main.cpp -LextB -lB -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The correct way to compile libB.so is:

```
g++ -c -fpic -I../extA b.cpp
g++ -shared -o libB.so b.o -L../extA -lA
```